# Adding spans/divs in hovered div

Tags: css, popup, hover

So my problem is that I have bunch of `<a>` that are displayed as block, and each one of them have background images. There are divs with spans on top and bottom of `<a>` block with info about that image (eg price, description etc..).

I need to be able to hover over `<a>` and display new div (or if you have better solution go for it), which will contain picture, few of spans of my choosing (every span inside that popup div should be span that belongs to `<a>`), and I need to be able to modify that div with css.

This is part of my html:

Now I got it so far that it pops up perfectly, but as you can imagine, I cannot add content inside that div little less edit and position that content.

```css
a {
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  float: top;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Green_eyes_kitten.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; }

  a .desc {
    display: block;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%; }

  a .price-tag {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #666666;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px; }

    a .price-tag .price {
      float: right;
      background-color: white; }

    a .price-tag .desc-sec {
      background-color: white; }

a:hover .popup {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1;
    width: 102%;
    height: 110%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white; }


    .normal {
      width: calc(20% - 20px);
      padding-bottom: calc(20% - 20px); }

      .wrapper .normal:nth-child(1) {
        width: calc(40% - 20px);
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: calc(40% - 20px);
        position: relative; }

        .wrapper .normal:nth-child(1) .price-tag {
          padding: 20px; }

      .wrapper .normal .desc {
        padding: 5px; }

      .wrapper .normal .price-tag {
        padding: 5px; } }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <a class="normal fir" href="#">
    <span class="desc">Lorem</span>
    <div class="price-tag">
      <span class="desc-sec">Ipsum</span>
      <span class="price">33 000,-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="popup"></div>
  </a>
  
  <a class="normal sec" href="#">
    <span class="desc">Lorem</span>
    <div class="price-tag">
     <span class="desc-sec">Ipsum</span>
     <span class="price">45 000,-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="popup"></div>
  </a>
  
  <a class="normal th" href="#">
    <span class="desc">Lorem</span>
    <div class="price-tag">
      <span class="desc-sec">Ipsum</span>
      <span class="price">25 000,-</span>
    </div><div class="popup"></div>
  </a>
  
  <a class="normal four" href="#">
    <span class="desc">Lorem</span>
    <div class="price-tag">
      <span class="desc-sec">Ipsum</span>
      <span class="price">55 500,-</span>
    </div>
   <div class="popup"></div>
  </a>
  
  <a class="normal fif" href="#">
    <span class="desc">Lorem</span>
    <div class="price-tag">
      <span class="desc-sec">Ipsum</span>
      <span class="price">45 500,-</span>
    </div>
   <div class="popup"></div>
  </a>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Just put the content straight into the divs. What's the problem?

Comment: I am an idiot, nothing else. :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need JS. Just add this in:

```
a .popup {
  display: none;
}
a:hover .popup {
  ...
  display: block;
}
```

You can put any content in there. https://jsfiddle.net/ctg09m6x/2/

Comment: Thank you. While I was waiting for response, I realized same thing. But still, thank you. :)